# Need to display a 20dp selected color block on Listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In listview, each item of listview as assign a color. color should visible on each list item on corner(20dp width). What is the best way to implement this color block.

Answer (score 0):

Define a layout for row.In your adapter in getView method set the color.

Answer (score 0):

found solution by myself. can find solution in another post added by myself:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16321832/1252454